# Flavor of a Traveling Salesman(TSP) using Boost::Graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, traveling-salesman

I need to find an optimal solution for a Travelling Salesman Problem on  graphs with the small number of vertices (< 10). Since this is an NP hard problem I am ready to do the brute force approach, for the small number of vertices it should be doable in a very small time.

I have a slightly modified conditions for 2 problems:

**(A)**

- The graph is bidirectional, with different weights in each direction.
- All vertices are connected to all.
- (Nice to have condition) You can visit the same vertices more than once, and travel the same paths more than once (however for eventual completeness you should not loop infinitely)

**(B)**

- In addition to conditions of **(A)**, here you need to visit a subset of vertices, while you still allow to travel through all other vertices of a graph. (given that it is a better solution).

A while back I have implemented a brute force solution and some heuristics like [Lin–Kernighan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lin%E2%80%93Kernighan_heuristic) (using simple matrix of weights), however I never used Graph data structures like in boost. And I was wounding if there is an existing implementation that I could use or a set of algorithms that could help me out to get optimal solution. Also I would appreciate if you could advise on how to get the part **(B)** right.

Thanks!